# Alert box not working with php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php if ($data == "") { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("review your answer1");
        window.location.href = "index1.php";
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("review your answer2");
        window.location.href = "index2.php";
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Alert box is not showing in above code as well as page is also not redirecting.
What is wrong in it?

Comment: It just doesn't show up?

Answer (score 4):

Do the other way around:

```
<script>
  var data = <?php echo $data; ?>
  if ( data === "" ) {
    alert("review your answer1");
    window.location.href = "index1.php";
  } else {
    alert("review your answer2");
    window.location.href = "index2.php";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving your code, it may require some adaptation:

```
<script>
   alert("review your answer<?echo $data;?>");
   window.location.href = "index<?echo $data;?>.php";
</script>
```